# divergent sum of radii in cover of unit disc by subdiscs

Tags: geometry

Suppose that a collection of more than one pairwise disjoint open discs (of various radii) is such that each disc is a subset of the unit disc $x^2+y^2 \le 1.$ Further assume the sum of the areas of these discs is $\pi,$ so that in a sense they exhaust the area of the unit disc. Must it then hold that the sum of the radii of the discs diverges?

Instead of open discs one can replace with closed discs which are allowed to meet only at points of tangency. It's clear geometrically that there need to be a countably infinite collection of discs in order that the total area be $\pi$, so the sum of squared radii will be $1$ and the question is then about the sum of the unsquared radii: Can the discs be somehow arranged so as to make the sum of unsquared radii convergent?

When this problem came up many years ago, some in our group had an approach based on assuming two of the discs were tangent at a point, and doing a circle inversion centered there. However I don't think it ever was made into a rigorous argument, and trying to estimate the effect of the inversion on small radii near the tangency point was never really nailed down.

I'd appreciate it if anyone has heard of this problem and can give a reference, or else perhaps give a sketch of an approach to the question which maybe is less dependent on inversion and the required estimates approach we used.

Comment: The first 32 terms of the series are calculated [here](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirRcir/).

Comment: @vadim123 The link you give is for specific packings given how many discs are to be placed. And as more circles are used, the circles in the packings are not a single sequence of circles. The question above is instead about whether one may somehow choose a *single* infinite sequence of circles whose area sum winds up $\pi$ but whose radius sum is finite, or else to show the radius sum must be infinite.

Comment: Intuition tells me that the smaller a circle becomes, the larger is the ratio between perimeter and area, so as circles become infenitesimally small, they have to reach an infinite ratio between perimeter and area. If you combine an infinite number of such small circles in order to cover a finite area, you have to multiply that finite area by the infinite ratio, reaching an infinite sum of radii. But that's not proof, just intuition.

Comment: @MvG I agree with that intuition, however it has to have something directly to do with the circular shapes not being able to get too close while covering. One can take an infinite sequence of three subsquares each of sidelengths in the sequence $1/2,1/4,1/8...$ and then (using repeated L shapes) cover all the area of a unit square, (so squared "radii" sum is 1), although the radii themselves only sum to 3.

Comment: We have been informed that this question is not entirely unrelated to problem M6 of the [MIT PRIMES 2016](https://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2016/entpro16.pdf) problem set. Since the question is older than the admission problem set, per our [policy](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774) we won't lock it (unless you request so). Anyway, the problems are slightly different.

Comment: And if you ping me in December, I'll be happy to link you to a paper containing the answer. I'm not doing it now because, policy aside, I'm not comfortable with doing it while the PRIMES admission contest is ongoing.

Comment: Since to me this problem is so similar to one part of problem M6 referred to in Daniel Fisher's comment, I would not mind, in fact would prefer, if it will be put on hold (lock or whatever) until the problem set deadline has passed.

Comment: Hey, i would love to have a link to a solution. Thank you in advance